# Unlit camera-facing billboard in ECS/DOTS shader

Tags: unity, shaders, entity-component-system, unity-dots

I'm attempting to create an unlit billboard shader for use in DOTS. I'm using quads to host the material

[image]

(Some regular, some DOTS for comparison purposes)

I've cribbed together something from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/AlexMerzlikin/ce756564414985039feff71ee79fefe6) and other sources to render a sprite where I want it, however, it's not oriented towards the camera.

```
Shader"DOTSTest/UnlitWithDotsInstancing"
{
    Properties
    {
        _BaseMap ("Base Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BaseColor ("Base Colour", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "RenderPipeline"="UniversalPipeline"
            "Queue"="Geometry"
            "RenderType"="Transparent"
            "PreviewType"="Plane"
        }

        //LOD100

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        ZWrite Off

        Pass
        {
            Name"Forward"
            Tags {
                "LightMode"="UniversalForward"
            }

            Cull Back

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma exclude_renderers gles gles3 glcore
            #pragma target 4.5
            #pragma vertex UnlitPassVertex
            #pragma fragment UnlitPassFragment
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing
            #pragma instancing_options renderinglayer
            #pragma multi_compile _ DOTS_INSTANCING_ON
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"

            struct Attributes
            {
                float4 positionOS : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 color : COLOR;
                            UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct Varyings
            {
                float4 positionCS : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 color : COLOR;
                            UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            CBUFFER_START(UnityPerMaterial)
            float4 _BaseMap_ST;
            float4 _BaseColor;
            CBUFFER_END

           
    

            #ifdef UNITY_DOTS_INSTANCING_ENABLED
                UNITY_DOTS_INSTANCING_START(MaterialPropertyMetadata)
                    UNITY_DOTS_INSTANCED_PROP(float4, _BaseColor)
                UNITY_DOTS_INSTANCING_END(MaterialPropertyMetadata)
                #define _BaseColor UNITY_ACCESS_DOTS_INSTANCED_PROP_WITH_DEFAULT(float4, _BaseColor)
            #endif

            TEXTURE2D(_BaseMap);
            SAMPLER(sampler_BaseMap);

            Varyings UnlitPassVertex(Attributes input)
            {
                Varyings output;

                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(input);
                UNITY_TRANSFER_INSTANCE_ID(input, output);

                const VertexPositionInputs positionInputs = GetVertexPositionInputs(input.positionOS.xyz);
                output.positionCS = positionInputs.positionCS;
                output.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(input.uv, _BaseMap);
                output.color = input.color;

                return output;
    
            }

            half4 UnlitPassFragment(Varyings input) : SV_Target
            {
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(input);
                half4 baseMap = half4(SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_BaseMap, sampler_BaseMap, input.uv));
                return baseMap * _BaseColor * input.color;
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
}
```

It works (which is to say it renders, I haven't tried varying colors yet). Before I get to that, I want to fix the orientation.

[image]

Previously, I've achieved that using something like this [also cribbed from other sources]

```
v2f vert(appdata v)
{
    v2f o;
    o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
    o.uv = v.uv.xy;

    // billboard mesh towards camera
    float3 vpos = mul((float3x3)unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex.xyz);
    float4 worldCoord = float4(unity_ObjectToWorld._m03, unity_ObjectToWorld._m13, unity_ObjectToWorld._m23, 1);
    float4 viewPos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_V, worldCoord) + float4(vpos, 0);
    float4 outPos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_P, viewPos);

    o.pos = outPos;

    UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o, o.vertex);
    return o;
}
```

And while it's worked, I have to admit I don't understand what it's doing in the transformations.

Whilst attempting to wire up that code, I noticed that the shader compiles just fine for use on a regular object, but the DOTS variant throws

> Shader error in 'DOTSTest/UnlitWithDotsInstancing': undeclared identifier 'unity_ObjectToWorld' at line 91 (on d3d11)
>
> ```
> Compiling Subshader: 0, Pass: Forward, Fragment program with DOTS_INSTANCING_ON
> Platform defines: SHADER_API_DESKTOP UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA UNITY_ENABLE_DETAIL_NORMALMAP UNITY_ENABLE_REFLECTION_BUFFERS UNITY_LIGHTMAP_FULL_HDR UNITY_LIGHT_PROBE_PROXY_VOLUME UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF1 UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION UNITY_USE_DITHER_MASK_FOR_ALPHABLENDED_SHADOWS
> Disabled keywords: INSTANCING_ON SHADER_API_GLES30 UNITY_ASTC_NORMALMAP_ENCODING UNITY_FRAMEBUFFER_FETCH_AVAILABLE UNITY_HALF_PRECISION_FRAGMENT_SHADER_REGISTERS UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER1 UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER2 UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER3 UNITY_LIGHTMAP_DLDR_ENCODING UNITY_LIGHTMAP_RGBM_ENCODING UNITY_METAL_SHADOWS_USE_POINT_FILTERING UNITY_NO_DXT5nm UNITY_NO_FULL_STANDARD_SHADER UNITY_NO_SCREENSPACE_SHADOWS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF2 UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF3 UNITY_PRETRANSFORM_TO_DISPLAY_ORIENTATION UNITY_UNIFIED_SHADER_PRECISION_MODEL UNITY_VIRTUAL_TEXTURING
> ```

[image]

I've tried swapping `unity_ObjectToWorld` for `_Object2World` to no avail.

If I include `UnityCG.cginc` I get a `_Time redefined` error (it appears to be clashing with `Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl`). Removing that include means I can no longer reference `UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID`.

Assuming this is the right approach, what's the DOTS-equivalent to `unity_ObjectToWorld`? And/or where do I need to import it from?

If not, how should I be handling this?

Edit: I've just found [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@10.0/manual/shaders-in-universalrp.html) page in the docs, which says

> - Declare all built-in engine properties, such as unity_ObjectToWorld or unity_WorldTransformParams, in a single CBUFFER called UnityPerDraw.

So I tried adding a

```
CBUFFER_START(UnityPerDraw)
float4x4 unity_ObjectToWorld;
CBUFFER_END
```

Which then fails to compile as unity_ObjectToWorld is being defined twice in the non-DOTS shader.

> Shader error in 'DOTSTest/UnlitWithDotsInstancing': redefinition of 'unity_ObjectToWorld' at line 69 (on d3d11)
>
> Compiling Subshader: 0, Pass: Unlit, Vertex program with

Moving it inside a conditional `#ifdef UNITY_DOTS_INSTANCING_ENABLED`

Compiles fine for non-DOTS (of course) but then fails DOTS with

> A BatchDrawCommand is using a pass from the shader "DOTSTest/UnlitWithDotsInstancing" that is not SRP Batcher compatible. Reason: "Builtin cbuffer size is not the same for all stages" (UnityPerDraw)
>
> This is not supported when rendering with a BatchRendererGroup (or Entities Graphics). MaterialID: 4 ("StarIcon"), MeshID: 1 ("Quad"), BatchID: 1.